Solana Playground - Mainnet-Beta
Hi Community,
I'm working on Solana Playground, I'm connecting my Phantom wallet. On devnet it works perfectly, but on mainnet-beta it shows a connection error.
I also tried to connect to several mainnet-beta service providers such as
solana config set -u https://rpc.ankr.com/solana
solana config set -u https://www.quicknode.com/chains/sol
also getting same error.
Thank you community for your help.



Check on the RPC URL you provided. You might be missing the API key. Please note that the default endpoint api.mainnet-beta.solana.com won't work

Refresh the wallet pop-up to show your wallet's transactions if it doesn't render upon connecting to phantom.


